# What forces might the bosonic superpartners of the fermions of the SM mediate?

Tags: particle-physics, fermions, supersymmetry, bosons

If the models of the universe that posit the existence of fermionic superpartners to the bosons, and bosonic superpartners to the fermions are correct, then what forces would be mediated by the squarks and sleptons?

If they are bosons, would they not be carriers of forces?

Comment: Sfermions have spin 0, not 1.

Comment: Does this mean that they cannot mediate a force? I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to say by pointing out that they have spin 1 as opposed to spin 0. Are you saying they are scalar bosons, like the Higgs?

Comment: You can say they have some similarities with the Higgs, yes. In the standard model (and most extensions), all fields (bosonic or fermionic) ultimately interact with all others and can therefore be said to both feel and mediate forces. But one thing that most massive objects we can actually handle have in common is that a dominant contribution to the forces they feel come from their interactions with spin-1 gauge fields. So "mediating a force" has taken on this meaning rather than being dropped from the particle physics literature for being imprecise.

Answer (score 1):

In particle physics the term "force" is used for the 3 electromagnetic , strong, weak couplings appearing in the Feynman diagram vertices. The term [fundamental is used](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/couple.html) to emphasize this.

At the macroscopic level all particle interactions are a "force" . No new couplings for the diagrams come from supersymmetry. [This link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/force.html) might help in understanding the use of the term "force".